# Remove quotes in Forfiles output {cmd}

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

So I am running this command:

```
FORFILES /S /M *.dmg /C "cmd /c if @fsize equ 1595694080 echo @fname"
```

and the output:

`"058-26174-078"`

but the problem is that I want the name without the quotations

like this: `058-26174-078`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I remove the quotes from a variable in a `cmd` shell?

You need to use `~` parameter extension together with `for /f` to do this.

Use the following command:

```
for /f %i in ('FORFILES /S /M *.dmg /C "cmd /c if @fsize equ 1595694080 echo @fname"') do @echo %~i
```

To set a variable, and in a batch file, use the following command:

```
for /f %%i in ('FORFILES /S /M *.dmg /C "cmd /c if @fsize equ 1595694080 echo @fname"') do @set MyVariable=%%~i
```

Notes:

- `%~1` Expand `%1` removing any surrounding quotes (")
- In a batch file replace `%i` with `%%i` and `%~i` with `%%~i`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the for command, here is an example:

```
@echo off
FORFILES /S /M *.dmg /C "cmd /c if @fsize equ 1595694080 set quote=@fname"
for %%a in (%quote%) do set dequote=%%~a
```

And you can use the %dequote% variable to get the dequoted string, I may have got the syntax wrong because I have never worked with the forfiles command.