# ForFiles: How can I prevent @FNAME from being wrapped in quotes?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I love the idea of using `forfiles` to do batch jobs on files, such as the following:

```
forfiles /m *.abc /c "cmd /c someprogram.exe -input @FILE -output @FNAME.xyz"
```

Except that this doesn't work because forfiles insists on wrapping `@FNAME` in quotes, resulting in the following:

```
someprogram.exe -input "my file.abc" -output "my file".xyz
```

which is invalid and fails.

**How can I prevent `@FNAME` from being wrapped in quotes?**

---

My hacky workaround is to echo the command rather than execute it, use another character (such as `*`) to mark the beginning and end of the filenames and then send the output to a temporary file:

```
forfiles /m *.abc /c "cmd /c echo someprogram.exe -input *@FILE* -output *@FNAME.xyz*" > go.bat
```

I then use powershell to remove all `"` and replace `*` with `"`.

```
powershell -Command (Get-Content go.bat) -replace '\"', '' -replace '\*', '\"' | Out-File -encoding ASCII go.bat
```

After the first line, `go.bat` contains:

```
someprogram.exe -input *"my file.abc"* -output *"my file".xyz*
```

and after the powershell, `go.bat` contains:

```
someprogram.exe -input "my file.abc" -output "my file.xyz"
```

which can now be executed.

([This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1026785/remove-quotes-in-forfiles-output-cmd) removes all quotes in the entire command line, which breaks on files and paths with spaces)

Comment: Use `for` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forfiles cannot do this. For however can.

In your batchfile, you would want to use the following:

```
for %%f IN (*.abc) DO someprogram.exe -input "%%F" -output "%%~nF.xyz"
```

This one-liner can also be used directly in CMD, if so, use the following instead:

```
for %f IN (*.abc) DO someprogram.exe -input "%F" -output "%~nF.xyz"
```

Comment: That should be `-output "%~nf.xyz`", otherwise you will get `"my file.abc.xyz"`

Comment: @DavidPostill well spotted. :) Edited.

Comment: I only saw it as I was just about to post a very similar answer but you got there first :)

Comment: A shame as I really liked `forfiles` - especially the recursive subdirectories and that `@FNAME` was easier to remember than `%~nF`. However it does seem that `for` is the better tool for the job.

Comment: for can also do recursive subdirectories by using `for /r c:\path %f IN...`

Comment: @DavidPostill you posted the comment half an hour before I posted the answer, so I thought you were not going to post an answer

Comment: @LPChip I'm not complaining :)